# Understanding the fisheye camera model proposed by Scaramuzza to undistort a fisheye image

Tags: c, matlab, computer-vision

I want to apologize for the broken english in this post. English is not my native language.

For a school project we are using a fisheye camera which needs to be undistorted.
The catch is however that we have to write all of our vision algorithms ourselves including the undistortion algorithm in C code.

I have been using the matlab camera toolbox to calculate the intrinsic parameters, but i find it difficult to understand how to apply these parameters with the given model that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5jVf.png)(if i even have to use it in the same way at all).

The [matlab page](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/fisheye-calibration-basics.html) and the [paper](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/IROS06_scaramuzza.pdf) also talks about stretching and shifting to go from the sensor plane to the image plane. Does this have to be incorporated into the algorithm?

Could someone explain how to undistort a distorted fisheye image to an undistorted image with this model?